# Jquery hide empty span in a div

Tags: jquery, html

I want to hide a span which is in a div, when it's null or undefined.

```
<div id="pricetag">1
    <div class="price">400</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>undefined</span>
</div>
```

So I want to have at the end:

```
1
400
hello
```

I tried something like:

```
$("#pricetag").filter(function () {
        return $('span', this).filter(function () {
            return $(this).text().trim() == 'null' || $(this).text().trim() == 'undefined' 
        }).length;
    }).hide();
```

But it doesn't work, it hides all the div.

```js
$("#pricetag").filter(function() {
  return $('span', this).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == 'null' || $(this).text().trim() == 'undefined'
  }).length;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pricetag">1
  <div class="price">400</div>
  <span>hello</span>
  <span>undefined</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `.filter()` the `<SPAN>` element and `hide()` them.

```
$("#pricetag span").filter(function () {
      return $(this).text().trim() == 'null' || $(this).text().trim() == 'undefined' 
}).hide();
```

```js
$("#pricetag span").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == 'null' || $(this).text().trim() == 'undefined'
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pricetag">1
  <div class="price">400</div>
  <span>hello</span>
  <span>undefined</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use selector [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to accomplish this task in one line:

```js
$('#pricetag span:contains(undefined),#pricetag span:contains(null)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pricetag">1
    <div class="price">400</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>undefined</span>
</div>
```